# Emulate iPhone app within another app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, emulation

I was wondering if I am able to emulate an iPhone app within an iPad app and allow people to use the iPhone application alongside the iPad app - by pressing a simple button, users would be able to use the other app. Obviously, this is an in-house application and not something that I'm launching to the App Store. Are there are libraries or framework available?

Thanks in advance - Daniel.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you really want. If you have different appId for iPhone and iPad version of the app then they can run side by side on iPad. If appId is the same, well, then the app is the same.

Comment: Essentially, I'm creating an application for the iPad that is basically a business card that will be on a table and people will be able to browse the business card on the iPad - as a software development company, I would like to be able to 'embed' our iPhone applications within the app so that people can use the iPhone application as if it were a normal device but within the iPad app - sorry if this is cryptic, it's actually harder to explain than I thought... Does that make sense?

Comment: I think i understand, but i'm not sure :) you're talking about some kind of 'showcase' meta-application? If that's correct: Apple hasa pretty strict rule on single task applications. Meta application (kind of second level springboard) would never pass the approval process.

Comment: Yes, but this is just for in-house use and will be run on our own iOS devices and placed around for people to use and wouldn't be submitted to the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to? The OS on the iPad can run iPhone applications natively. This is actually a requirement for iPhone applications.